# How to resolve optional nested type like std::allocator_traits?

Tags: c++, c++11

An allocator can optionally have nested types like `pointer`, `const_pointer`. But one can always use these interface with `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>`, which would provide a default version of these types if they are absent in `Allocator`.

How is `std::allocator_traits` implemented? How can a template choose a default version of nested type when it's absent?

Comment: Google terms: SFINAE, SFINAE type introspection, Boost type traits.

Comment: [Alisdair Meredith: Making Allocators Work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkiYOP3d64E).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to refer to the type `T::pointer` in a context where it does not cause an error if it is not a valid type, instead it causes template argument deduction to fail. The general form of this is known as SFINAE, which stands for "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error". For a explanation of how it works see my [SFINAE Functionality Is Not Arcane Esoterica](http://accu.org/content/conf2013/Jonathan_Wakely_sfinae.pdf) presentation.

There are various techniques, often involving overloaded function templates, but my current favourite uses the `void_t` idiom to select a partial specialization of a class template:

```
template<typename T>
  using void_t = void;

template<typename T, typename = void>
  struct get_pointer
  {
    using type = typename T::value_type*;
  };

template<typename T>
  struct get_pointer<T, void_t<typename T::pointer>>
  {
    using type = typename T::pointer;
  };
```

Now given an allocator type `A` you can use `typename get_pointer<A>::type` to refer to `A::pointer` if that exists, otherwise `A::value_type*`

The code above works because when `A::pointer` is a valid type the partial specialization matches and is more specialized than the primary template, and so gets used. When `A::pointer` is not a valid type the partial specialization is ill-formed, so the primary template is used.

Comment: Great example, but I can't seem to compile your example on MSVS 2013 and G++(-std=c++11) with a class that does not contain a definition for `pointer`. Perhaps you could take a look at it?

Comment: @Nard, fixed now, sorry about that, the `decltype` was bogus, you don't need to use `decltype` to get the type of a type! (You would use something like `decltype(some_expression)>` to check the validity of an expression, but to check for `T::pointer` it's just `void_t<typename T::pointer>`)

Comment: @ It also doesn't compile if T is a class that does not have a pointer defined. Everything just defaults to the primary template.

Comment: @Nard, it works with clang 3.4 or gcc 5, older compilers might not be good enough and need the more traditional SFINAE using overloaded function templates

Comment: I see. I'm using g++ 4.8.2 and I hear MSVS has some problems with SFINAE but I'm not sure about that. Sorry to bother you again but is there a name for this idiom other than `void_t`? I'm having trouble finding it on Google. :/

Comment: That's its name, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3911.pdf and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FliKwcwXE for more details