# how to check if a type is defined by typedef or using in template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I want to declare a member type that depend on the template parameter:

```
template< typename T >
struct bc_allocator_traits
{
public:
    using this_type = bc_allocator_traits;
    using allocator_type = T;
    using value_type = typename allocator_type::value_type;
    using pointer_type = typename allocator_type::pointer_type; 
...
```

In this example `pointer_type` depend on the template parameter(`allocator_type`). but defining `pointer_type` for template parameter is optional and if template parameter doesn't present this type, i want to use a default type like `value_type*`.

Is there any way to achieve this optional member type definition in my classes?

Comment: related: [How to resolve optional nested type like std::allocator_traits?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27549857/3953764)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is like the posterchild for `void_t`.

```
template<class ...>
using void_t = void;

// workaround for some compilers: 
// template<class...> struct voider { using type = void; }; 
// template<class... Args> using void_t = typename voider<Args...>::type;

template<class T, class = void>
struct pointer_type_or_default { 
    using type = typename T::value_type*;
};

template<class T>
struct pointer_type_or_default<T, void_t<typename T::pointer_type>> { 
    using type = typename T::pointer_type;
};
```

and then

```
using pointer_type = typename pointer_type_or_default<allocator_type>::type;
```

The idea is that the partial specialization is viable and used only if `T::pointer_type` is valid and denotes a type.

The workaround is needed for compilers not implementing the resolution to [CWG 1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558). This includes GCC up to 4.9.2 (the current trunk version compiles the alias template version correctly, see [PR 63825](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63825)), and apparently MSVC.

Comment: I think your additional workaround is for VC++ not GCC. I'm using VC++ compiler Nov 2013 CTP and without that workaround program has errors. thank you for your great solution.

Comment: @JayMiller As far as I can see, the alias template works on GCC trunk but [not with Coliru's GCC 4.9.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c934253af56bd267).